# Wrapping a block with a block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a method that takes a block as an argument.  That block needs to be augmented and then passed to a library function that block as an argument.  An example:

```
typedef void (^eblock_t)(void);

void libraryFunction(eblock_t block);

- (void)myMethod:(eblock_t)block {
    libraryFunction ( ^{
        block();
        NSLog(@"block executed");  // This is the augmentation of the block
    } );
}
```

That example is pretty straight forward and works for straight forward situations.  I evolved that example a bit to the following using GHUnit.  It is a bit contrived, but works to illustrate my problem as concisely as possible:

---

### EBlock.h

```
typedef void (^eblock_t)(void);

@interface EBlock : NSObject {
    eblock_t _block;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) eblock_t blockOption1;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) eblock_t blockOption2;

- (void)chooseBlock:(NSUInteger)option;
- (void)executeBlock;

@end
```

---

### EBlock.m

```
#import "EBlock.h"

@implementation EBlock

- (void)chooseBlock:(NSUInteger)option {
    if (1 == option) {
        // This is a block wrapping a block to augment the block
        // This is the source of problem with test_switchOption_1For2
        _block = ^{
            self.blockOption1();
            NSLog(@"option1");  // This is the augmentation 
        };
    } else {
        // There is no block wrapping the block and thus no augmentation of the block
        // There is no issue with test_switchOption_2For1
        _block = self.blockOption2;
    }
}

- (void)executeBlock { _block(); }

@end
```

---

### Test_EBlock.h

```
@class EBlock;

@interface Test_EBlock : GHTestCase

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger counter1;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger counter2;

- (void)incrementCounter1;
- (void)incrementCounter2;

@end
```

---

### Test_EBlock.m

```
#import "Test_EBlock.h"
#import "EBlock.h"

@implementation Test_EBlock

- (void)incrementCounter1 { _counter1++; }

- (void)incrementCounter2 { _counter2++; }

- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    _counter1 = _counter2 = 0u;
}

- (void)tearDown { [super tearDown]; }

- (void)test_option1 {
    EBlock *foo = [[EBlock alloc] init];
    foo.blockOption1 = ^{ [self incrementCounter1]; };
    foo.blockOption2 = ^{ [self incrementCounter2]; };
    [foo chooseBlock:1];

    [foo executeBlock];
    GHAssertEquals(self.counter1, 1u, nil);
    GHAssertEquals(self.counter2, 0u, nil);
}

- (void)test_option2 {
    EBlock *foo = [[EBlock alloc] init];
    foo.blockOption1 = ^{ [self incrementCounter1]; };
    foo.blockOption2 = ^{ [self incrementCounter2]; };
    [foo chooseBlock:2];

    [foo executeBlock];
    GHAssertEquals(self.counter1, 0u, nil);
    GHAssertEquals(self.counter2, 1u, nil);
}

- (void)test_switchOption_1For2 {
    EBlock *foo = [[EBlock alloc] init];
    foo.blockOption1 = ^{ [self incrementCounter1]; };
    foo.blockOption2 = ^{ [self incrementCounter2]; };
    [foo chooseBlock:1];

    // switch what is done in the block
    foo.blockOption1 = ^{ [self incrementCounter2]; };

    [foo executeBlock];
    GHAssertEquals(self.counter1, 1u, nil);  // This fails 
    GHAssertEquals(self.counter2, 0u, nil);  // This fails
}

- (void)test_switchOption_2For1 {
    EBlock *foo = [[EBlock alloc] init];
    foo.blockOption1 = ^{ [self incrementCounter1]; };
    foo.blockOption2 = ^{ [self incrementCounter2]; };
    [foo chooseBlock:2];

    // switch what is done in the block
    foo.blockOption2 = ^{ [self incrementCounter1]; };

    [foo executeBlock];
    GHAssertEquals(self.counter1, 0u, nil);
    GHAssertEquals(self.counter2, 1u, nil);
}
```

---

### Discussion

Test: `test_option1`, `test_option2`, & `test_switchOption_2For1` pass.

`test_switchOption_1For2` fails because of `GHAssertEquals(self.counter1, 0u, nil);` and `GHAssertEquals(self.counter2, 1u, nil);`

This is because the block that is being executed `self.blockOption1` is actually `[self incrementCounter2]` and not `[self incrementCounter1]`.  This is because in `EBlock.m` `chooseBlock` the block wrapping the block has copied `self.blockOption1` which at the time of evaluation is `[self incrementCounter2]`.  Is there a better way to augment the block so the block does not have to be wrapped?  Or is there a way not to delay the evaluation of `self.blockOption1` so that it is `[self incrementCounter1]`.

Comment: The assertions in your discussion do not match the code. The code is asserting that counter 1 is *1* and counter 2 is *0*, which would occur if the block was evaluated when it was chosen. Your discussion asserts that counter 1 is *0* and counter 2 is *1*, which would occur if the block was evaluated when it was run.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw you are correct let me refactor my question.  The asserts should be true, they are not.  My discussion was wrong (it was late).

Comment: @ughoavgfhw I fixed the discussion section. I had mixed up what I had wanted to happen with what had actually happened. All good now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is captured by your wrapping block is `self`, not the value of `self.blockOption1`. If you want to capture the latter, try:

```
- (void)chooseBlock:(NSUInteger)option {
    if (1 == option) {
       eblock_t local_block = self.blockOption1;
        // This is a block wrapping a block to augment the block
        _block = ^{
            local_block();
            NSLog(@"option1");  // This is the augmentation 
        };
    } else {
        // There is no block wrapping the block and thus no augmentation of the block
        // There is no issue with test_switchOption_2For1
        _block = self.blockOption2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally, I see the forest. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you wish to delay the effect of `chooseBlock` until `executeBlock` to that the block can be changed between them. Just rearrange your logic (typed directly into SO, could be tided up):

```
#import "EBlock.h"

@implementation EBlock
{
   NSUInteger currentChoice;
}

- (void)chooseBlock:(NSUInteger)option
{
   currentChoice = option;
}

- (void)executeBlock
{
    if (1 == option)
    {   // This is a block wrapping a block to augment the block
        // This is the source of problem with test_switchOption_1For2
        _block = ^{
            self.blockOption1();
            NSLog(@"option1");  // This is the augmentation 
        };
    }
    else
    {
        // There is no block wrapping the block and thus no augmentation of the block
        // There is no issue with test_switchOption_2For1
        _block = self.blockOption2;
    }

    _block();
}

@end
```

Comment: Admittedly, this is contrived example to illustrate the problem that I am having with GCD, without adding the complexity of multiple threads. I agree rearranging the logic solves the issue with the example code, but does not work with GCD. Calling `chooseBlock` simulates calling from `dispatch_source_set_event_handler` while `executeBlock` simulates the thread executing the block.  Switching the block via `foo.blockOption1 = ^{ [self incrementCounter2]; }` simulates calling a second time prior to the block code being executed.

Comment: @mmorris  - so the answer is right, it is the question that is wrong... ;-) Unfortunately I think your attempt to simplify the question has failed. Submit a new question, from your comment it sounds like `dispatch_source_set_event_handler` should do what you want, but presumably it is not.

Comment: Believe it or not, I have no issue with GCD.  My issue is with the code that I have written that interacts with GCD. Which is what is in the question, simplified by not including GCD.  I am looking for a better way to build a block based on a block that is being supplied -or- a way for `EBlock` `chooseBlock` `self.blockOption1()` to be evaluated (partially) so that `Test_EBlock`'s `[self incrementCounter1]` is in the block that will be evaluated by `EBlock` `executeBlock`.  That was a mouthful. ;)

Comment: @mmorris - There isn't a better way to wrap a block in a block - do exactly as you have done, define a block and within it call the other block. You can't pull a block apart and inject code into it. Why is this causing a problem for you? If all you want to do is freeze the value of blockOption1 into the wrapped block then do `eblock_t now = self.blockOption1; _block = ^{ now(); ... }`.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to copy the block that came in as a argument/property. Try go with:

```
@property (copy) eblock_t block;
```

Comment: Copying `^{ self.blockOption1(); NSLog(@"option1"); };` does not solve the problem as `self.blockOption1()` is evaluated the same way, `[self incrementCounter2]`, when called by `executeBlock` as it does as a strong reference.

Comment: What is needed to achieve what I am trying to do is have `self.blockOption1()` expand/evaluate/??? to `Test_EBlock`'s `[self incrementCounter1]`

Comment: @mmorris Are you 100% sure that you have retained _every_ block and object involved? Try turn on `NSZombie` and catch all `NSExceptions` with lldb. Or maybe you need to catch the `-dealloc`'s. If you are using GCD, maybe you need to use some alternative way to organize your tasks and blocks.